# Return first row number in range where string matches any part of cell contents

Tags: excel

Say I have three cells (one in each row):

```
A1
Apple Pear Lime Grape
Tom Bob Cliff Steve
Pi Rho Sigma Theta
```

There is a string of text in each single cell.  Is there a formula I can write that will return the first row in which a given value appears?

For example, say I had cells like this:

```
Pear     1
Cliff    2
Steve    2
Pi       3
```

I would like to return the row where that value is a match for the original array of strings.  I have experimented with `SEARCH`, `FIND`, and others, but these are good for comparing one row to another single row.  I'm looking for something that will examine a whole array of rows and return the first reference row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use MATCH with wildcards:

```
=MATCH("*"&C1&"*",A:A,0)
```

[image]